# Spring Boot get the request body while using @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm using Spring Boot @RequestBody annotation to access the request body properties like below

```
@PostMapping
ResponseEntity<UserDto> createUser (@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    // some coode
    return null;
}
```

What I want to do is instead of just accessing the userDto properties. I want to log the whole request body because someone else is using sending the request and it doesn't match my `userDto`

What I tried?

```
@PostMapping
ResponseEntity<UserDto> createUser (HttpServletRequest request) {
    logger.info("Body: {}", request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    return null;
}
```

This works just fine but each time I want to log the request body I have to switch between `@RequestBody UserDto` and `HttpServletRequest request`

Is there anyway I can keep that jackson `@RequestBody` annonation and still log request body as it is?

Comment: Did you try: logger.info("Body: {}",userDto); ? It doesn't work?

Comment: Did you override `toString` method for `UserDto`?

Comment: If you want to log the whole request, you should use a filter. Have a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging theres a CommonsRequestLoggingFilter you can use.

Comment: To be honest, I would do this with a servlet filter on Spring's servlet to get access on the actual, binary request stream.

Comment: @TomStroemer CommonsRequestLoggingFilter works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information taken from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

You can use Springs CommonsRequestLoggingFilter for this. You can activate this via a Configuration Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter           = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

The filter logs on debug, so you need to enable debug logging for the class. For example add this in your logback.xml:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>
```

For reference see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper from fasterxml

add the following dependencies to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

Change your createUser method to this:

```
@PostMapping
ResponseEntity<UserDto> createUser (@RequestBody UserDto userDto)
throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    logger.info("Body: "+  objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userDto));
    return null;
}
```

Result will be like this in your console:

```
: Body: {"name":"John","username":"Doe"}
```

Comment: The result is not original request body. It contains only those properties that are present in UserDto class. OP's intent is to trace original JSON with properties missing in UserDto class.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this task is to write an Http Filter that logs the message before the Handler method is called.

This [Baeldung Article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter) demonstrates a filter that logs.